# The data racing issue cannot be reproduced with this snippet of code

Tags: c, multithreading

I have the below snippet of code with which I want to use to show the case of data racing in the C multithreading programming. And I compiled and ran it with `gcc test.c -O0 -lpthread -o test && ./test` on an x86 Linux system (with only a single core), for near a hundred times, but I didn't see any case that the printed value is incorrect (200000). Does it mean that the x86 or the compiler could guarantee that every modification on an `int` variable is thread-safe? Or anything wrong with my program?

**Edit**: so, as @Sinic and I tested, the question would be updated to:
**Why does data racing rarely happen on a single-core CPU? Or there won't be any data racing issues on a single-core CPU?** Because, AFAIK, the threads would be scheduled randomly even on a single-core CPU. So, the result would be a mess as well.

```
// test.c
#include <threads.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define THREAD_COUNT 20
#define THREAD_LOOP 10000
int counter = 0; 
int run(void* data) {
  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_LOOP; i++)
    counter++;  // <- each thread would modify the global variable counter here.
  printf("Thread %d terminates.\n", *((int*) data));
  return thrd_success;
}
int main(void) {
#ifndef __STDC_NO_THREADS__
  int ids[THREAD_COUNT];
  thrd_t threads[THREAD_COUNT];  
  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
    ids[i] = i + 1;
    thrd_create(&threads[i], run, ids + i);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
    thrd_join(threads[i], NULL);
  printf("Counter value is: %d.\n", counter); 
#endif
  return 0; 
}
```

Got a snapshot of the assembly code of the run function as shown below, and also pointed out the corresponding code for `counter++`.

[image]

Comment: Even with optimizations disabled, are you sure that the compiler simply doesn't unroll the loop in the `run` function? Have you taken a look at the generated assembly code? And have you tried to make the `counter` variable `volatile`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I got a screenshot of the assembly implementation of the function run.

Comment: I ran the code on a Ryzen 3900X (12 core + SMT) in a loop 10000 times: the counter never hits exactly 200000. It ranges from 13770 to 107813 with an avg. of 30774.

Comment: @Sinic Is it possible that this issue relates to the fact that I ran it on a single-core CPU?

Comment: @Becavalier Absolutely. If i pin the process to only one core, there are (out of 10000 tests) ~9548 correct results. So more than 95%. I assume that is because it is much less likely to get scheduled exactly while the counter update happens on a single core machine than on a multicore machine. The correct results drop to 47% with two cores and to 9% with three cores

Comment: And for completeness: compiled with `-O3` the counter update becomes a single `addl` instruction, which (at least for me) solves the problem of the data race.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean that the x86 or the compiler could guarantee that every modification on an int variable is thread-safe?

**No**, on x86/x86-64 platforms this is **not thread-safe** (like on most platforms). The assembly code proves that the operation is not done atomically.

> Or anything wrong with my program?

Well, **possibly**. The threads are not guaranteed to be executed at the time time. If the operating system takes some time to create each thread, the loop may actually be executed serially. 10000 iterations is not a lot and *mainstream modern processors can execute the loop in a very short time* (eg. few micro seconds), typically *less than the time required to create new threads*. You can mitigate the problem by using **more iteration and a barrier**.

> I didn't see any case that the printed value is incorrect (200000).

This is not the case on my machine which does not use [simultaneous multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) (eg. HyperThreading). This shows that the problem is dependent of the execution or the hardware.

> Is it possible that this issue relates to the fact that I ran it on a single-core CPU?

**Yes**, indeed.

The race condition mainly comes from the fact that one core can request for a given cache line that is used by another thread. The value fetched could be not up to date. On x86/x86-64 platforms, when a core writes to a cache line, it invalidates the copy in other cores. However, it still cause an issue because the operation are not done atomically.

If you only use 1 core and 1 hardware thread, then the software threads are executed serially (in an interleaved way) during a given **quantum which is likely much bigger than the time to execute the loop**. In this case, this means the overall execution is sequential and you should see no problem. If the quantum is smaller than the time to execute the loop, then the problem should appear since the thread can be interrupted in the middle of the loop (and the value fetched will be modified by other threads meanwhile).

You can use `numactl --physcpubind=0` on Linux to pin your process to a given core. On my machine, I can *confirm that the problem do not appear if only one core is used*. However, it does appear with at least 2 cores. If I also set `THREAD_LOOP` to a value 10000 times bigger, the results is *not* the same anymore. This confirms the quantum hypothesis explained above.

Comment: "[...] can execute the loop in a very short time [...] less than the time required to create new threads" seems to be correct. 
If i do 100000 iterations, the number of correct results (tested at 1000 runs) drops to 0.4% when pinned to a single core. (instead of 98.6% at 10000 iterations)

Comment: Do you mean that the interval of the thread re-scheduling is higher than the execution duration of the loop? So, every thread can complete its execution before the creation of the next thread or the start of the next thread?

Comment: That is exactly what i think happens if the loop does not live long enough. That would cause a serial processing of the threads what would mitigate the race condition. So if you increase the loop size on your single core machine, you should see a similar behavior

Comment: In your case, I think the time to create the threads does not matter a lot. What matter is the quantum allocated to execute each thread. Indeed, even if the threads are created, they are not directly *scheduled* on a 1 core hardware (with 1 hardware thread). The operating system (OS) will schedule one of them for a given quantum (eg. 1 ms). The thing is the target thread just a fraction of this time to execute the loop (eg. 10 us). Once the function returns, the OS schedule another thread and so on. In the end, the whole execution is sequential *without context switches*.

Comment: If the number of iterations is much bigger, then 1 quantum is not enough to execute all the iteration of a thread and the OS does some context switches in the middle of the loop that makes the race condition visible. It is more clear?

Answer (score -1):

> Does it mean that the x86 or the compiler could guarantee that every modification on an int variable is thread-safe?

No. That something works when you tested it does not mean there's a guarantee -- *ever*.

> Or anything wrong with my program?

Yes, your program has a data race. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.